# Is it possible to check if the input is an integer without hasNextLine and exit loop if it's 0?

Tags: java, string, loops

My method works perfectly,but I want to exit the loop if 0 is entered.I know I can use getArray.hasNextInt() and then if the input was an integer put into a new variable and then check again if it's 0,then leave the loop,but I think that'd be too long  of a code and needs at least two other variables(an integer and a boolean) to be created.
I have written a method like so:

```html
  public static char[] play() {  //Takes a string from the user,checks if the length is 5,and converts to character array.
 boolean fiveChars =false;
 System.out.println("Please enter your input: ");
 Scanner getArray = new Scanner (System.in);
 
 while(!fiveChars) {
  String gotArray = getArray.nextLine(); 
 if(gotArray.length()==5) {
    myInput=gotArray.toCharArray();
 break;}
 else
 {   if(gotArray.charAt(0)==0 && gotArray.length()==1) {
     a++;
     menu();
     break;}
     else
     System.out.println("Please try again!Your input should consist of 5 characters!");
        System.out.println("giving a new input doesn't count as one of your choices.");
 }}
 
    return myInput;
 }
```

But it doesn't work.I want to know why

```html
if(gotArray.charAt(0)==0 && gotArray.length()==1)
```

Blockquote
doesn't work here.Also,would you please tell me if there is a shorter way that works exists?Thanks.

Comment: A character '0' does not have a value of 0, you should compare with a '0', note the single quotes

Comment: Oops how didn't I notice-Thank you so much!

Comment: I wrote the code about a month ago and I wasn't much of a clean coder back then so I don't want to make it messier or add anything,because I'm just fixing a few bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either

```
if(gotArray.charAt(0)=='0' && gotArray.length()==1)
```

OR

```
if(Integer.parseInt(gotArray.charAt(0))==0 && gotArray.length()==1)
```

should work.